# Health Check Fails After Upgrading Spring Boot from Version 2 to 3 on AWS Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: spring-boot, health-check

I'm encountering an issue with my Spring Boot application while attempting to upgrade from Spring Boot version 2 to version 3 on AWS. The application runs successfully with Spring Boot 2, but after migrating to Spring Boot 3, I'm experiencing health check failures.

Specifically, the health check for the AWS Elastic Load Balancer reports that the service is unhealthy with the following message:

```
service ocorp_dev_pporocessor port 443 is unhealthy in target-group ocorp-dev-tg due to (reason Health checks failed with these codes: [403]).
```

Here are some additional details:

1. The application builds successfully with Spring Boot 3, and there are no apparent errors during the build process.
2. I haven't made any other significant changes to the application code or configuration, apart from migrating to Spring Boot 3.
3. The health check was successful when using Spring Boot 2, indicating that the issue might be related to the Spring Boot version upgrade.

I'm looking for insights into why this health check failure is occurring with Spring Boot 3 and any suggestions on how to resolve it. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with error messages from AWS's load balancer, but assuming that `403` is an HTTP status code, the request to the health endpoint was forbidden. Working on that assumption, I would check your security configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, Andy. When I was checking the security configuration I realized that the problem was the database connection and I solved it.